# Zoo Flexible Admin EE3

Tags: devdemon, zoo

I can't seem to find any information on whether the add-on Zoo Flexible Admin is going to be ported to EE3. DevDemon has been less than helpful and has no information about what they are going to do with this add-on. Has anyone been able to find out whether or not Zoo Flexible Admin will be ported to EE3?

Answer (score 0):

Zoo Flexible Admin will be updated. There is a missing hook in EE3 which the EE2 version of Zoo Flexible Admin used which requires some additional work to get it working in EE3.

We are currently busy with Subscriptions and Store for EE3.

Comment: Do you have a general idea when you all will get to this?

Comment: Any new on Zoo Flexible Admin for EE3? I also could not find a changelog online anywhere..?